# Paypal return a variable issue

Tags: php, paypal

I'm have an issue with Paypal, i'm using a simple form :

```html
<html>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="boukhersya@gmail.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="DEMANDE D ETUDE PERSONNALISEE">
 <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>

 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id=val value="79">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value= "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/etude-gratuite.php" >
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/etude-personalisee/test.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/etude-personalisee/paimentconfirme.php">
 
     <input type="submit" value="Payer votre commande">
 
</form>
```

I want to return the email used in the payment, so i can know which user has paid 
so i can get the email in the page test.php, can i do that with PDT ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the field "custom" to pyapal and it will pass it back to you when the transaction is completed.  You may want to use your user ID rather than an email address though.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="email@address.com">
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

The way it works is: you use these hidden input values on for your paypal button.  When the user is transferred to paypal all of these values are sent with it.  One of the values you use is name="notify_url" when the user completes checkout paypal posts the checkout information to that url.  In the case of php you do something like this:

```
$useremail = $_POST['custom']
```

Any custom information you want to have returned to you needs to go in the custom field.  I use some kind of delimiter if I want more pieces of information returned, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="user@email.com-firstname-userID">
```

Then you just explode the data:

```
$paypalvars = explode("-", $_POST['custom']);
$email = $paypalvars[0];
$firstName = $paypalvars[1];
$userID = $paypalvars[2];
```

Whatever value is in the custom filed will be posted back to your notify_url exactly the same way you give it to paypal.

Comment: How can i get it back ?? using return like :<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/etude-personalisee/paimentconfirme.php?custom">

Comment: Here is the page i'm working on http://asso.thirdeyellc.net/etude-personalisee/test.php, it doesn't work for me, can you check it please

Comment: The custom field will be posted back to the url you specify as the notify_url.  From your page it looks like you don't have a notify_url set up in your button.

Comment: Now i'm testing on the cancel_return, and i added the notify_url, i should get the user email when the user cancel the order as well, is that possible ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Paypal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) API to handle this.

Simply set up IPN within your Paypal account and then create a file which will manage the data that gets sent back upon payment.

This includes their email address too!

Note that the `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url">` should be the input used to direct to test.php because at the moment, the information that will get passed back to you will be sent to the etude-gratuite.php

Comment: Their paypal email address may not match the email address they use for his site.